Flutter tester.widget() doesn't update state
Use case: The checkbox should be disabled if user doesn't scroll to the bottom of the content. The app works properly then I write a widget test for it.
This code failed at the final line, because the onChanged is still null:
Checkbox checkBox = tester.widget(find.byType(Checkbox)) as Checkbox;
expect(checkBox.onChanged, null);
await tester.drag(scrollFinder, const Offset(0, -5000));
await tester.pumpAndSettle(); 
//checkBox = tester.widget(find.byType(Checkbox)) as Checkbox;
expect(checkBox.onChanged, isNotNull);

When debugging the test with UI, I see the checkbox on screen was enabled, but the checkbox in the test is still null. I have to retrieve the checkbox again to make it work:
checkBox = tester.widget(find.byType(Checkbox)) as Checkbox;

I wonder whether it is an expected behavior of flutter_test or a bug as it requires to write more code.
